# how record video by result websocket by mediarecorder in android studio

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

I receive esp32cam camera images in ByteBuffer format using websocket and upload them online using wifi.
Receiving this content is like an infinite loop that returns 25 frames per second and by converting these ByteBuffers to Bitstamps, I show them in imageView.
So far so good and I have a preview of snapshots without sound.

The problem is that I can't record these images in real time like recording video with a mobile phone.
In addition to video recording, I also need to mix the sound on the video at the same time.
The sound should be taken separately from the mobile microphone and mixed on the video.

Finally I need to record in full video with audio to external memory from websocket.

This is my code.

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Open");
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
                try {
                    encoder.finish();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Receive");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message) {
                byte[] imageBytes = new byte[message.remaining()];
                message.get(imageBytes);
                final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
                if (bmp == null) {
                    return;
                }
                bitmapList.add(bmp);
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (bind!=null){
                            mainImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
```

Using the jcodec library, I stitched the bitmaps together and the video was made without sound, but it took a lot of time.
For every 15 seconds, one minute of time was required for streaming, which was not possible for long periods of time